# List of Stopwatches - restarting begins all timers due to binding

Tags: c#, list, xamarin, binding, stopwatch

Hope you can help ... I have a list of activities which use a stopwatch to track each one of their activity durations. When I tap an activity in my list, it starts the stopwatch for the activity tapped and when I tap the activity row again it stops the stopwatch and resets it.

However when I then tap another activity, although it is really only updating the duration for the activity tapped in the backend, the frontend UI updates all of the activities timers with the same activity time tapped because they are binded to the same activityduration element. I don't know how to only change the activity duration for the activity tapped in the front end. Could anyone advise on how to do this without re-structuring my model/collection? Or will I have to make a subnest for the activity name in my collection?

On tap event in code behind:-

```
public async void OnActivityTap(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            var item = (ViewCell)sender;
            UserActivities.Activities myactivitiesModel = item.BindingContext as UserActivities.Activities;

            if (myactivitiesModel == null)
            {return;}

            // OnPropertyChanged("ActivityDuration");
            // mystopwatch.Reset();
            //ViewModel.getUserActivities();

            foreach (var x in ViewModel.UserActivitiesList) {

                if(x.ActivityName == myactivitiesModel.ActivityName) {
                        int seconds = 1;

                    //if the activity is not enabled and the activity is tapped
                    if (myactivitiesModel.ActivityEnabled == false)
                    {
                        //enable the activity and start the stopwatch
                        myactivitiesModel.ActivityEnabled = true;

                        //Get the current duration and add it onto the stopwatch start time
                        ts =  x.ActivityDuration; 

                        //Reset the stopwatch back to zero
                                       
                        mystopwatch = new Stopwatch();
                        //Start the stopwatch
                        mystopwatch.Reset();
                        mystopwatch.Start(); 

                        while (myactivitiesModel.ActivityEnabled == true)
                        {
                            Device.StartTimer(TimeSpan.FromSeconds(seconds), () =>
                            {
                          
                             myactivitiesModel.ActivityDuration = (mystopwatch.Elapsed + ts);
                  
                                return true;
                            });

                            return;
                        }
             
                    }
                    else if (myactivitiesModel.ActivityEnabled == true)
                    {
                        //disable the activity and stop the stopwatch
                        x.ActivityEnabled = false;

                        //Stop the clock
                        mystopwatch.Stop();
                       
                        
                        //Store activity time stopped
                        await MongoService.UpdateUserActivityTime(userIdentity, myactivitiesModel.ActivityName, x.ActivityDuration);

                        //Store the time stopped in the UserActivitiesList binded to the UI list
                        x.ActivityDuration = myactivitiesModel.ActivityDuration;
                        OnPropertyChanged("ActivityDuration");

                        return;
  
                    }

                } //end of if activityName Tapped
  
            } //end of foreach

        } //end of OnTap Activity
```

Model:

```
public class UserActivities : INotifyPropertyChanged
    {

        [BsonId, BsonRepresentation(BsonType.ObjectId)]
        public string Id { get; set; }

        string _foreignUserID;
        [BsonElement("foreignUserID")]
        public string foreignUserID
        {
            get => _foreignUserID; set
            {
                if (_foreignUserID == value)
                    return;

                _foreignUserID = value;

                HandlePropertyChanged();
            }
        }

        [BsonElement("activities")]
        public ObservableCollection<Activities> UserTimedActivities { get; set; }

        public class Activities : INotifyPropertyChanged
        {
            

            string _activityName;
            [BsonElement("activityName")]            
            public string ActivityName
            {
                get => _activityName; set
                {
                    if (_activityName == value)
                        return;

                    _activityName = value;

                    HandlePropertyChanged();
                }
            }

            TimeSpan _activityDuration;
            [BsonElement("activityDuration")]            
            public TimeSpan ActivityDuration
            {
                get => _activityDuration; set
                {
                    if (_activityDuration == value)
                        return;

                    _activityDuration = value;
                    HandlePropertyChanged();
                }
            }

            TimeSpan _activityGoalDuration;
            [BsonElement("activityGoalDuration")]            
            public TimeSpan ActivityGoalDuration
            {
                get => _activityGoalDuration; set
                {
                    if (_activityGoalDuration == value)
                        return;

                    _activityGoalDuration = value;

                    HandlePropertyChanged();
                }
            }

            Boolean _activityEnabled;
            [BsonElement("activityEnabled")]            
            public Boolean ActivityEnabled
            {
                get => _activityEnabled; set
                {
                    if (_activityEnabled == value)
                        return;

                    _activityEnabled = value;

                    HandlePropertyChanged();
                }
            }

            public Activities(string activityname, TimeSpan activityduration, TimeSpan activitygoalduration, Boolean activityenabled ) {
                ActivityName = activityname;
                ActivityDuration = activityduration;
                ActivityGoalDuration = activitygoalduration;
                ActivityEnabled = activityenabled;
            }

            void HandlePropertyChanged([CallerMemberName] string propertyName = "")
            {
                PropertyChanged?.Invoke(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs(propertyName));
            }

            public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged;
        }

        public UserActivities(ObservableCollection<Activities> usertimedactivities)
        {
            UserTimedActivities = usertimedactivities;
        }

        public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged;

        void HandlePropertyChanged([CallerMemberName] string propertyName = "")
        {
            PropertyChanged?.Invoke(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs(propertyName));
        }
    }
```

ViewModel method to compile list-

```
public async void getUserActivities()
        {
            var userActivities = await MongoService.GetUserActivityData(userIdentity);

            try
            {
                if (IsBusy)
                    return;
                IsBusy = true;
                UserActivitiesList.Clear();

                foreach (var x in userActivities)
                {
                    foreach(var y in x.UserTimedActivities) {

                        //foreach (var y in x.userActivities)
                        UserActivitiesList.Add(y);
                    }
                }
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                IsBusy = false;
                Debug.WriteLine(ex);
            }
            finally
            {
                IsBusy = false;
            }
        }
```

**2. Alternative Timer method suggested by Jason (doesn't get elapsed time or  update UI):**

```
 public async void OnActivityTap(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            var item = (ViewCell)sender;
            UserActivities.Activities myactivitiesModel = item.BindingContext as UserActivities.Activities;

            if (myactivitiesModel == null)
            { return; }

            foreach (var x in ViewModel.UserActivitiesList)
            {

                if (x.ActivityName == myactivitiesModel.ActivityName)
                {
                    if (x.ActivityEnabled == false)
                    {
                        x.ActivityEnabled = true;
                        timer.Enabled = true;
                        timer.Start();
                        timer.Elapsed += OnTimedEvent;
                        x.ActivityDuration = x.ActivityDuration.Add(new TimeSpan(0, 0, 0, 0, (int)interval)); //new
                        return;
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        x.ActivityEnabled = false;
                        timer.Enabled = false;
                        timer.Stop();
                        x.ActivityDuration = x.ActivityDuration.Add(new TimeSpan(0, 0, 0, 0, (int)interval)); //new
                        return;
                    }
```

**3. Alternative approach with stopwatch - does work but doesn't update UI until tapped **

```
 foreach (var x in ViewModel.UserActivitiesList)
            {

                if (x.ActivityName == myactivitiesModel.ActivityName)
                {
                    if (x.ActivityEnabled == false)
                    {
                        x.ActivityEnabled = true;
                        //timer.Enabled = true;
                        mystopwatch.Restart();
                        mystopwatch.Start();
                        x.ActivityDuration = mystopwatch.Elapsed + x.ActivityDuration;
                        NotifyPropertyChanged("ActivityDuration");
                        //timer.Elapsed += OnTimedEvent;
                        //x.ActivityDuration = x.ActivityDuration.Add(new TimeSpan(0, 0, 0, 0, (int)interval)); //new
                        return;
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        x.ActivityEnabled = false;
                        //timer.Enabled = false;
                        mystopwatch.Stop();
                        x.ActivityDuration = mystopwatch.Elapsed + x.ActivityDuration;
                        NotifyPropertyChanged("ActivityDuration");
                        //x.ActivityDuration = x.ActivityDuration.Add(new TimeSpan(0, 0, 0, 0, (int)interval)); //new
                        return;
                    }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you're making this way too complicated.  I would create a single timer and do something like this

```
using System.Timers;

...


// 100ms == .1s
double interval = 100;

// CREATE ONE TIMER FOR ALL ACTIVITIES
Timer timer = new Timer(interval);
timer.Elapsed += UpdateTimers;
timer.Start();

...

private void UpdateTimers(object sender, EventArgs a)
{
  // this is psudocode, update for your model
  foreach(var a in Activities)
  {
     // if activity is selected
     if (a.Active) {
       // update the elapsed time
       a.Elapsed = a.Elapsed.Add(new Timespan(0,0,0,0,interval));
     }
  }
}
```

**Final Solution as implemented by OP**

```
public page() 
{
            timer.Start();
            timer.Elapsed += UpdateTimers;
}

        private void UpdateTimers(object sender, EventArgs a)
        {

            foreach (var x in ViewModel.UserActivitiesList)
            {
                if (x.ActivityEnabled)
                {
                    x.ActivityDuration = x.ActivityDuration.Add(new 
                    TimeSpan(0, 0, 0, 0, (int)interval));
                }
            }
        }
```

Comment: Hi Jason, thanks for your help. I've tried your line 'a.Elapsed += interval;' but I receive the error, Operand += cannot be applied to timespan or double as my ActivityDuration element is a timespan. How can I make this work?

Comment: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.timespan.add?view=net-5.0

Comment: a.ActivityDuration.Add(timer.Elapsed); doesn't work - what is the method for easily capturing the timer's elapsed time to add onto my duration - this should be a simple add but it doesn't work...

Comment: "Returns a **new** TimeSpan object..."

Comment: and as I note in my example, you should increment by the interval value each time the timer fires

Comment: Thanks Jason, but this still doesn't capture the elapsed time and assign it to my the ActivityDuration. Please see the updated question with your method, (I have multiple activities listed so the time starts and stops for each activity tapped).

Comment: what you implemented is not what I suggested.  My entire suggestion is based on a **single timer** and then updating each activity's elapsed counter when the timer fires.  All the tap event should do is toggle each activities status, not start/stop any individual timers.

Comment: But your solution doesn't get the elapsed time or calculate the elapsed time when add the activity was tapped/stopped. So, I've added another alternative approach because stopwatch works better and timer isn't easily manipulated however the UI doesn't update each second so with this approach, that is all that is remaining, so how do I continuously update the UI based on this approach? I've notified the property, but it only updates on tap.

Comment: each activity has it's own elapsed property, correct?  Each time the timer fires each activity should be updated with one more time increment.

Comment: Yes, each activity has it's own activity duration stored so the elapsed time will need to added onto that while its enabled... a.Elapsed = a.Elapsed.Add(new Timespan(0,0,0,0,interval)); doesn't return the elapsed time or update the UI...

Comment: those are two separate problems and should be considered separately.  For the first, every time the timer fires the Elapsed value should be incremented by `interval`.  If that is not working, you need to debug it to find out why.  For the UI not updating, you need to be sure that `ActivityDuration` is calling `PropertyChanged` and that the Activity model is implementing INPC